# How to sum and count on a data.table grouped by values in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.frame that I have constructed using a XML file, and now I want to count and sum its values, something like count and sum in SQL.

This is how the data.frame looks:

```
   msgDataSource msgFileSource processDate msgNumRows
1        source1       Quarter  2015-01-30         30
2        source1         Month  2015-01-30         15
3        source1         Month  2015-01-30         20
4        source1          Year  2015-01-30          1
5        source2       Quarter  2015-01-30         30
6        source3       Quarter  2015-01-30         15
7        source1          Year  2015-02-01         80
8        source2          Year  2015-02-01         90
9        source1       Quarter  2015-02-01          5
10       source2       Quarter  2015-03-15          9
11       source3       Quarter  2015-03-15         14
```

This is what I need

```
   processDate msgFileSource msgDataSource sumDataSources   countDataSources
 1:  2015-01-30         Month       source1             35                 2
 2:  2015-01-30       Quarter       source1             30                 1
 3:  2015-01-30       Quarter       source2             30                 1
 4:  2015-01-30       Quarter       source3             15                 1
 5:  2015-01-30          Year       source1              1                 1
 6:  2015-02-01       Quarter       source1              5                 1
 7:  2015-02-01          Year       source1             80                 1
 8:  2015-02-01          Year       source2             90                 1
 9:  2015-03-15       Quarter       source2              9                 1
10:  2015-03-15       Quarter       source3             14                 1
```

This is what I am able to get so far:

```
   processDate msgFileSource msgDataSource sumDataSources
 1:  2015-01-30         Month       source1             35
 2:  2015-01-30       Quarter       source1             30
 3:  2015-01-30       Quarter       source2             30
 4:  2015-01-30       Quarter       source3             15
 5:  2015-01-30          Year       source1              1
 6:  2015-02-01       Quarter       source1              5
 7:  2015-02-01          Year       source1             80
 8:  2015-02-01          Year       source2             90
 9:  2015-03-15       Quarter       source2              9
10:  2015-03-15       Quarter       source3             14
```

And this is my code:

```
dfFullData <- data.frame (
    msgDataSource = c("source1", "source1", "source1", "source1", "source2", "source3", "source1", "source2", "source1", "source2", "source3"),
    msgFileSource = c("Quarter", "Month", "Month", "Year", "Quarter", "Quarter", "Year", "Year", "Quarter", "Quarter", "Quarter"),
    processDate = c("2015-01-30", "2015-01-30", "2015-01-30", "2015-01-30", "2015-01-30", "2015-01-30", "2015-02-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-03-15", "2015-03-15"),
    msgNumRows = c(30, 15, 20, 1, 30, 15, 80, 90, 5, 9, 14),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
summaryTable <- data.table(dfFullData)
summaryTable <- summaryTable[
                        order(processDate, msgFileSource, msgDataSource),
                        sum(msgNumRows),
                        by=list(processDate, msgFileSource, msgDataSource) 
]
setnames(summaryTable, "V1", "sumDataSources")
print(summaryTable)
```

Is there a way to calculate the count on one pass, or should I count it separately and then perform an cbind?

How do I achieve what I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `list` to make a list of the summary columns that you want in your aggregated `data.table`. Use the in-built symbol `.N` to find the number of rows in your subset:

```
summaryTable <- summaryTable[
                        order(processDate, msgFileSource, msgDataSource),
                        list(sumDataSources=sum(msgNumRows), 
                             countDataSources=.N),
                        by=list(processDate, msgFileSource, msgDataSource) ]
```

Using `list` this way will also mean that you don't need to use `setnames` later, since you have already named your columns in your `list`.

---

This is not relevant to the actual question but, as detailed by the comments below this answer, the use of an additional `order` in the above command can be negated by using `keyby` instead of `by`. The final command will look like this:

```
summaryTable <- summaryTable[, list(sumDataSources=sum(msgNumRows), 
                                    countDataSources=.N),
                        keyby=list(processDate, msgFileSource, msgDataSource) ]
```

`keyby` also has the additional benefit of setting it's arguments as the keys for the resulting table, the ordering of which is a by product from this process.

Comment: Nice. Any reason for `order()` here? Also `length(.)` is just `.N` - special inbuilt symbol.

Comment: @Arun didn't know about `.N`, thanks! `order()` is used because OP is using it, and it does affect the ordering of the resulting table. No other reason though.

Comment: Mattrition, right. The operation doesn't really depend on the order. So you can use `keyby` in place of `by`, instead of using `order()` - `keyby` will order the data by grouping columns *after* aggregation - which is much more efficient as it orders on the aggregated data. Check [these new HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for more info.

Comment: @Mattrition Thanks!, I was trying to assign it to a list, but I got an error everytime I tried.

Comment: @Arun So if I use summaryTable [, list(sumDS, countDS), keyby=list(col1,..., colN)], I will get the values ordered after processing, right? I thought that -the first- order was for that purpose.

Comment: @Arun I tried with list(sumDataSources=sum(msgNumRows), countDataSources=.N) and list(sumDataSources=sum(msgNumRows), countDataSources=length(.)) and I got different results. With the first one, I got 2, and with the 2nd I got 1. However, I used keyby=list(processDate, msgFileSource, msgDataSource) and it orders it.

Do you know why?

Comment: @StrayChild01, on your first comment, exactly. On the 2nd, I don't see anything wrong by running your data. Make sure you're looking at the right row.

Comment: @Arun Hi Arun, you stand correct, I was putting some other column. As soon as I changed it to countDataSources=length(msgDataSource), I got the 2 I was looking for.

Comment: @Arun Sorry that I ask you too much. Why this happens? Is it because it merges the values and the count is after the group by?

Comment: @StrayChild01, why what happens?

Comment: @Arun Sorry. That I get 1s with all the other columns.

Comment: @StrayChild01, I can't reproduce the issue. If you can provide the code and the data, I'd be happy to take a look and see what's the issue.

Comment: @Arun This is the only change to the code: summaryTable <- summaryTable[,list(sumDataSources=sum(msgNumRows),countDataSources=length(.)),keyby=list(processDate, msgDataSource, msgFileSource)]. See this screenshot: http://imgur.com/z6NY1jy

Comment: @StrayChild01, `.` is just a placeholder (I was just lazy to write the entire variable name under comment). What I meant was `length(msgNumRows)`.

Comment: @Arun I am really sorry. I thought that it was something like ".N" or another pre-set value. Could you put it as an answer so I can set yours as correct?

Comment: @StrayChild01, `.N` and `length(msgBumRows)` should give exactly the same result, and `.N` is the idiomatic way. I'd accept Mattrition's answer (unless you're facing some issues).. Or you can answer it yourself and accept it. Good luck!

Comment: @Arun I accepted Mattrition Answer, but I upvoted all your answers. That's the least that I can do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mattrition Thanks for the edit, I actually changed the code to order after the values are summarized.